# Makefile for a system

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build an application where there are two different systems interacting with each other and most of their functionalities are common. So I'm planning a directory structure like this.

```
Xxx
|_sys1
|
|_sys2
|
|_common
```

Each have a separate include and src directories.

Learned from a little browsing that keeping the compilation of common as `libcmn.so` will be efficient and can be linked for compiling `xxx` and `yyy`.

Though I understand how to create a `.so`, using them in a makefile with variables and linking header files are new to me.

Can someone guide me on how the Makefile for each should be and how linking should be done for a proper build?

Comment: You'd better use a static library than a shared library (`.a` extension), avoiding the need to modify your `LD_PRELOAD`or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @Chnossos He doesn't necessarily have to change these if he places the libraries in a known location (such as `/usr/local/lib`), or if he passes `-rpath` to the linker (assuming `ld` on Linux). I'd prefer sticking to dynamic libraries unless there really is a very strong reason to go with a static approach.

Answer (score 0):

To compile xxx and yyy that use your libcmn.so, they just need to include the library interface header.

To link with the library just add a `-lcmn` and `-Lpath/to/your/lib` to your LDFLAGS

To be noted that using this method, you will need to :

- Add the library path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- or add the library path to ldconfig
- or move the library to a place where ldconfig looks already (/usr/lib for example)

You can also use the [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) and [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) functions to map your libcmn functions to function pointers at runtime. This will allow you to specify the path and name of the library to load at runtime and avoid the LD_LIBRARY_PATH problem.

You will need to add the `-ldl` flag to compile using this technique

Answer (score 0):

In a make(1) control file, sequencing is important.  Here is the general rule:

```
Targets placed on the same prerequisites line may be build concurrently.  Order is preserved between different <code>Makefile</code> targets.  So something like this:

all:: a b

a:: a.o lib/libfoo.so
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ a.o -Llib -rpath=lib -lfoo.so ${LDLIBS}

b:: b.o lib/libfoo.so
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ b.o -Llib -rpath=lib -lfoo.so ${LDLIBS}

lib/libfoo.so:
    ${MAKE} -C lib all
```

Now, on a big server you can do this:

```
$ make -j10 all
```

and everything will be built in the right order.  Just be sure there is a `Makefile` in the `lib` directory that knows how to build the library.

Unless `libfoo.so` is significantly large, I'd make it a static libary, then you would not have to pre-program where to find it later at runtime.